# Как при нажатии на кнопку на клавиатуре закрыть форму в WinForms. НА С++?

Tags: c++, winforms

Как при нажатии на кнопку на клавиатуре закрыть форму в WinForms. НА С++ !!!!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3526752/how-to-make-a-form-close-when-pressing-the-escape-key

Answer (score 0):

Для того чтобы закрыть форму в WinForms при нажатии на кнопку на клавиатуре в C++,Вам следует использовать обработчик событий:

```
void Form_KeyDown(Object sender, KeyEventArgs e) {
        // Если нажата клавиша Esc (код 27), закрываем форму
        if (e->KeyCode == Keys::Escape)
        {
            this->Close();
        }
}
```